# Why am I getting this error? "name 'get_sorted_run_length' is not defined"

Tags: python, data-structures

Im just trying to call the function get_sorted_run_length from another function called natural_merge_sort, but when I call it. I get the error "name 'get_sorted_run_length' is not defined".
This is how I am calling it:

```
def natural_merge_sort(self, integer_list):
        get_sorted_run_length(integer_list, 0)
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 43, in main
    sorter.natural_merge_sort(list5_copy)
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/NaturalMergeSorter.py", line 17, in natural_merge_sort
    get_sorted_run_length(integer_list, 0)
NameError: name 'get_sorted_run_length' is not defined
```

I only have one local variable on the get_sorted_run_length function and tried to put ir global but that didn't do anything.

I have 3 files, main.py, RunLengthTestCase.py, and NaturalMergeSorter.py. I think that the error is in the NaturalMergerSorter.py

The full code for that file is:

```
class NaturalMergeSorter:
def __init__(self):
    return

def get_sorted_run_length(self, integer_list, start_index):
    counter = 1
    for i in range(start_index, len(integer_list)-1):
        if integer_list[i] <= integer_list[i+1]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            return counter
    if(counter == 1):
        counter = 0
    return counter   # Modify this line.

def natural_merge_sort(self, integer_list):
    get_sorted_run_length(integer_list, 0)
    index = 0
    index = get_sorted_run_length(self,integer_lsit,index)
    if index == len(integer_list):
        return integer_list
        i = 0
    else:
        get_sorted_run_length(integer_list, index)
        merge()
    
    return integer_list # Comment out this line.

def merge(self, numbers, left_first, left_last, right_last):
    merged_size = right_last - left_first + 1

    merged_numbers = [None] * merged_size
    merge_pos = 0
    left_pos = left_first
    right_pos = left_last + 1

    # Add smallest element from left or right partition to merged numbers
    while left_pos <= left_last and right_pos <= right_last:
        if numbers[left_pos] <= numbers[right_pos]:
            merged_numbers[merge_pos] = numbers[left_pos]
            left_pos += 1
        else:
            merged_numbers[merge_pos] = numbers[right_pos]
            right_pos += 1

        merge_pos += 1

    # If left partition isn't empty, add remaining elements to merged_numbers
    while left_pos <= left_last:
        merged_numbers[merge_pos] = numbers[left_pos]
        left_pos += 1
        merge_pos += 1

    # If right partition isn't empty, add remaining elements to merged_numbers
    while right_pos <= right_last:
        merged_numbers[merge_pos] = numbers[right_pos]
        right_pos += 1
        merge_pos += 1

    # Copy merged numbers back to numbers
    for merge_pos in range(merged_size):
        numbers[left_first + merge_pos] = merged_numbers[merge_pos]
```

Comment: Without seeing your code -- in particular, where `get_sorted_run_length` is defined in relation to `natural_merge_sort` -- we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Is get_sorted_run_length defined in your class or outside of your class?

Comment: I have added the full code for the file where I think the error is happening

Comment: `get_sorted_run_length()` is an attribute of the class, so you need to put `self.` in front of it.  `self.get_sorted_run_length()`

Comment: I got rid of that error, but now when I call the function it tells me that the function "get_sorted_run_length() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given", isn't the 3 parameters 'get_sorted_run_length(self, integer_list, index)'. Or am I also doing it wrong?

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` as an actual argument.  Python takes care of that automatically.  Just call it with two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:

You have to add 'self' to your method calls if they are defined inside your class.

```
self.get_sorted_run_length(integer_list, 0)
```

This let's python know to look within the current class for the function definition, otherwise it's searching for it defined globally, and it's not there.

Comment: So for every function that has self as a parameter, I have to call them like that?

Comment: Yes, you do. It defines the scope just like globally and locally Python needs to know where to look for it.